# Cheapest Gin in the UK?

Tags: spirits, gin, online

Just visiting the good old UK, and discover that gin is so expensive - what and where can I buy a cheap gin in the UK, are there any online stores? Yes I have looked but to no avail.  Thanks guys.....

Comment: all alcohol is expensive in the UK for tax reasons. What do you mean by "cheapest"? How much are you willing to skimp on quality?also would you describe £15 per litre as cheap?

Comment: where about in the UK and what kind of gin you after are you looking for known brads or willing to try anything?

Comment: @Jamie Eltringham Willing to try as my liver is still in tact (I think), and for the sake of my art I will put my liver and soul forward so that others may follow!

Answer (score 2):

I buy quite a lot of Gin from Amazon and their prices are often cheaper than the main UK supermarkets on a direct match basis, but not against Aldi or Lidl who often sell almost identical products to say Bombay Sapphire, but at a much cheaper price.

Answer (score 1):

In Scotland we have MUP (minimum unit pricing) which means you cannot sell alcohol for less than 50p per unit of alcohol so an average bottle of gin (38%) cannot be sold for less than £13.88 per 75cl bottle. The rest of the UK doesn't have this law so can be sold as low as cost price so is subject to supplier but can start from as low as £10 per 75cl bottle. 
The following link is for a calculator to work out how much you can legally charge for alcohol in Scotland (oh and don't forget the 'no incentive to buy more' no multi-buy offers meaning no buy 2 get 3rd free etc deals). 
https://app.calculoid.com/#/calculator/50913

Answer (score 1):

Just go to a supermarket (the bigger the better and I'd suggest Tesco or Asda) and buy their own brand london dry. It's not nice but it's cheap. If you really don't mind the taste, consider vodka instead as it's often a little bit cheaper and essentially the same stuff without the botanicals.

[Tesco gin](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/261852634)

[Asda gin](https://groceries.asda.com/product/gin/asda-london-dry-gin/1363592)

[Sainsburys gin](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/gin-340887-44/sainsburys-dry-london-gin-15l)

You're unlikely to get it for under £14 per L but you might find it on offer occasionally.

Answer (score -1):

Gordon's London Dry Gin in a clear plastic bottle with a yellow label is the cheapest gin I've ever seen, but it's tasty and potent. You can find it in nearly any liquor store, or online if you're really not up to walk around the corner to a store. Do not confuse it with the Gordon's Gin which is in a green glass bottle with white text. Happy travels!